# pulling data from a SQL database table

Tags: c#, sql

I am pulling 25 random numbers between the range of 1-35 questions stored in SQL based on there ID number (1,2..20 etc) this is so a user taking the test will be given random questions from the question pool in SQL I am trying to get the SQL parameter to increment within the loop variable "a" is being used as the key to enter values into the respected arrays.

Sample code is below

```
    protected void Question_Fetch(int[] Mixed_Questions) 
    //this array is loaded with my mixed numbers between 1-35(no duplicates) the array length //is 25 
    {
        Question_String_list = new string[25];
        Question_Answers = new string[25];
        Num_Answers = new string[25];
        Types_Of_Question = new string[25];
        User_Answers = new string[25];
        isLocked = new string[25];

        using (SqlCommand Comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Question_String, Question_Answer, Type_Of_Question, Possible_Answers FROM Question_Pool WHERE Question_ID = @Question_ID", Conn))
        {
            SqlParameter IDParam = Comd.Parameters.Add("@Question_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            for (int a = 0; a < Mixed_Questions.Length; a++)
            {
                int Random_Number = Mixed_Questions[a];
                Comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question_ID", Random_Number);
                Conn.Open();                                        
                SqlDataReader rdr = Comd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    IDParam = Mixed_Questions[a];
                    //Random_Number = Mixed_Questions[a];
                    //Comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question_ID", Random_Number);
                    Question_String_list[a] = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    Question_Answers[a] = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    Types_Of_Question[a] = rdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    Num_Answers[a] = rdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    Conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Answer_Controls();
        Init_Test_Details();
    }
```

Comment: Are you really using classic ASP? Also why are you using parallel arrays instead of an array of objects?

Comment: no sorry the classic asp tag is a mistake.
this is still early in this application development and I am a co op student I will Look into array of objects just seemed easier at the time when I was coding any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to pull 35 random questions might be to do something like this:

```
select top 35 * from Question_Pool order by (newid())
```

This effectively randomises the questions before taking 35 of them. This way you can do it all in a single query rather than 35 queries.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well. Also, If the user has the ability to take the "test" multiple times, you might want to include a where clause to ensure the user always sees questions they have never been asked before: select top 35 * from Question_Pool where QuestionId not in (select QuestionId from Answers where AnsweredByUserId=@UserId) order by (newid())

Comment: Great Thank You very much I will give this a try.

It works perfectly!!
@Paul Stovell Thank you again I have spent far too much time today on this.